# SQL Server - Select in select doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query, which returns 10 rows:

```
SELECT 
    substring(testcase_name, 4, len(testcase_name))
FROM 
    TEST_RESULTS 
WHERE 
    test_run_id = 48 
GROUP BY 
    substring(testcase_name,4,len(testcase_name))
```

I need to count these rows (need return number - in this case 10). I need

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (my query)
```

but in SQL Server this doesn't work. I searched on the internet and I tried like `SELECT count(\*) FROM (my query) t` .. I named the returned table "t" .. but still doesn't work for me..

Error message is:

> No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'.

Maybe problem could be that I am modifying data with substring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add alias to expression:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT substring(testcase_name,4,len(testcase_name)) 
      FROM TEST_RESULTS 
      WHERE test_run_id = 48 
      GROUP BY substring(testcase_name,4,len(testcase_name))
     ) t(s);   -- adding column alias
```

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me! :) so I just needed to name also the column  right?

Comment: @Horhc Exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will give you the count of grouped records. What you might however need is the count per group, which you could do like so:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT substring(testcase_name,4,len(testcase_name)) AS x
    FROM TEST_RESULTS 
    WHERE test_run_id = 48 
)
SELECT x, COUNT(*) AS CountPerX
FROM cte
GROUP BY x;

x    CountPerX
--------------
Foo  123
Bar  234
```

Another way to return the "count of groups" (your original question), is via `COUNT DISTINCT`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT substring(testcase_name,4,len(testcase_name))) AS CountGroups
FROM TEST_RESULTS 
WHERE test_run_id = 48;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also an opportunity to use `COUNT DISTINCT`, for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct substring(testcase_name,4,len(testcase_name)))
FROM TEST_RESULTS 
WHERE test_run_id = 48;
```

Also note that in this form you no longer need the group by.